# How to match last substring

Tags: xstring, stringstrings

I am working on displaying source code for which I pass a path to
a macro. Now I am wondering if it is possible using `xstring` or
`stringstrings` to match from after the last delimiter, i.e. `/` to
the end of the string to determine the filename.

Example: I might pass `../code/subfolder/project/code.java` to the macro for
which I want to extract the substring `code.java`. It seems easy to match the first occurrence of a character, but not the last.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

No package is needed for that, you can use LaTeX's filename parser:

```
\documentclass{article}

\begin{document}

\makeatletter

\filename@parse{../code/subfolder/project/code.java}

[\filename@area]

[\filename@base]

[\filename@ext]

\end{document}
```

Comment: Accepted because it is the simplest answer (and most highly voted), but in all honesty all answers given are of equal high quality. Each answer has its own advantages/disadvantages.

Answer (score 6):

Here is a method with xstring:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{xstring}
\newcommand*\filename[1]{%
    \IfSubStr{#1}/
        {\StrCount{#1}/[\ossepoccur]%
        \StrBehind[\ossepoccur]{#1}/\relax
        }
        {#1}%
}
\begin{document}
\filename{abc.foo}

\filename{../code/subfolder/project/code.java}
\end{document}
```

Answer (score 4):

Here's a generic extractor of the last item in a delimited string:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{xparse}

\ExplSyntaxOn
\NewDocumentCommand{\extractlast}{O{/}mo}
 {
  \seq_set_split:Nnn \l_stroobants_string_seq { #1 } { #2 }
  \IfNoValueTF { #3 }
   {
    \seq_item:Nn \l_stroobants_string_seq { -1 }
   }
   {
    \tl_set:Nx #3 { \seq_item:Nn \l_stroobants_string_seq { -1 } }
   }
 }
\seq_new:N \l_stroobants_string_seq
\ExplSyntaxOff

\begin{document}

\extractlast{../code/subfolder/project/code.java}

\extractlast[-]{a-b-c-def}[\test]

\texttt{\meaning\test}

\end{document}
```

The first optional argument is the delimiter, default `/`; the trailing optional argument is a macro name where the last item is stored, if not present, the item is printed.

[image]

A fully expandable version, but with a fixed delimiter; you're better not input an empty string, although a test for this can be easily added.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{xparse}

\ExplSyntaxOn
\DeclareExpandableDocumentCommand{\extractlast}{m}
 {
  \stroobants_extractlast:nn #1 / \q_nil / \q_nil /
 }
\cs_new:Npn \stroobants_extractlast:nn #1 / #2 / \q_nil /
 {
  \str_if_eq:nnTF { #2 } { \q_nil }
   {% end of recursion
    #1
   }
   {% go on
    \stroobants_extractlast:nn #2 / \q_nil /
   }
 }
\ExplSyntaxOff

\begin{document}
\extractlast{../code/subfolder/project/code.java}

\edef\test{\extractlast{../code/subfolder/project/code.java}}
\texttt{\meaning\test}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Answer (score 2):

Here is a way with `stringstrings`.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage{stringstrings}
\def\fname#1{%
  \findchars[q]{#1}{/}%
  \edef\tmp{\theresult}%
  \convertchar[e]{x#1}{/}{ }%
  \getaword[q]{\thestring\ }{\numexpr\tmp+1\relax}%
  \edef\thefname{\thestring}%
}
\begin{document}
\fname{../code/subfolder/project/code.java}
The file is \thefname.
\end{document}
```

[image]